# CodeIgniter with AJAX not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm become crazy with ajax and codeigniter together! Normally AJAX always work when i test it without any framework but now i'm building an application web with CodeIgniter and i need to use AJAX but it's happened something of incredible!

I want that if you press a button, before submit, you check with ajax if the name in input text is already exist in database and if exist see a confirm alert "Are you sure of overwrite?", ok i followed some tutorial and suggest but nothing that resolve my problem...

I put here the code, i need help!

File **selection.js**

```
$(function() {
    $(".deleteSel").click(function(e) {

    var sel = $(this).attr("name");
    if (!confirm("Sei sicuro di cancellare la selezione?")) {
        // your deletion code

        e.preventDefault(); 
    }


});
$(".confirmSel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var sel = $( "input[name='selection']" ).val();
    //$(".prova").html(sel);
    $.ajax({
        'url': "/index.php/pdf/check",
        'type': "POST",
        'data': {selection: sel},
        'success': function(msg) {
            $(".prova").html(msg);
            if (msg == 'no') {
                if (!confirm("Il nome scelto esiste già! Sovrascrivere?")) {
                    // your deletion code

                    e.preventDefault(); 
                }
            } 
        },
        'error': function() {
            alert("C'è stato un qualche errore!");
        }
    });



});
});
```

The function in pdf controller:

```
 public function check() {
    $this->load->model('selections_model');
    if($this->selections_model->checkSelection($this->input->post('selection')))
        echo "no";
    else
        echo "si";
}
```

And the html part

```
 Vuoi salvare le selezioni? <input type="text" name="selection" placeholder="Nome della selezione..." class="form-control alias selection"> <input class="btn btn-default confirmSel" type="submit" name="submit" value="Salva">
```

I have try even to print "msg" in a generic div and this coming out:

[image]

Comment: Is your `index.php` at the root of your server?

Comment: No but i have tried in all chance even without index.php but the result is the same

Comment: `url': "/index.php/pdf/check"` Is going to the root of your server. Have you tried it with your directory? `url': "/directory/index.php/pdf/check",`

Comment: I think that Ajax is not the problem here. Is your url valid? Without using ajax, just go to the url in browser to the function check(). Print something and check it first.